# Replace text before and after pattern in one command in vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following text

```
bar1 = foo.get('abc1')
bar2 = foo.get('abc2')
bar3 = foo.get('abc3')
```

and I would like to search and replace all the occurrences of `foo.get(...)` with `foo[...]` in order to obtain:

```
bar1 = foo['abc1']
bar2 = foo['abc2']
bar3 = foo['abc3']
```

How could I do that in vim in one search/replace command?

Comment: if it is just a matter of enclosings, there are a lot of plugins for that https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich and more

Answer (score 2):

The following should work: `:%s/foo.get(\(\W\+\)\(\w\+\)\(\W\+\))/foo\[\1\2\3]`.

Here, the main logic is to store `'`, `abc1` and `'` to `\1`, `\2` and `\3` which can later be back referenced. Similarly for other two lines.

Comment: I like this idea! I simplified it by removing the pattern matchings of `'` since they are constant for all strings: `:%s/foo.get('\(\w\+\)')/foo['\1']/g`

Comment: Vimgolf: with a substitution `:%s/foo\zs.get(\(.*\))/[\1]/` or with normal `:%norm f.cf([<c-v><esc>$r]`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think would be to select those three lines using VISUAL mode (press `v`, and `hjkl/arrows` to select the lines) - the advantage of visual mode is that you can select which lines to launch the substitute command on.

[image]

then press `:` to launch a command on those lines selected in visual mode (`:'<,'>`part should add itself automatically):

`:'<,'>s/foo.get('\(.*\)')/foo['\1']`

so this simple regex basically selects `foo.get('somewords')` and replaces them with `foo['somewords']` (`somewords` being group 1)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
:g/foo\.get/exec "norm! f(r[\<Esc>f)r]"
```

Let's break down the whole command to be more didactic:

```
 g/foo\.get/ .................... match all the lines with "foo.get"
 exec ........................... calls command execution
 norm! .......................... normal mode
 f(r[ ........................... jumps to the ( and replaces it with [
 \<Esc> ......................... literal Esc (only works between double quotes)
 f)r] ........................... the final substitution
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a one shot regex for this specific pattern, you can use:

```
:%s/foo\.get(\(.*'\))/foo[\1]/c
```

or if there are possible spaces to contend with:

```
:%s/foo\.get *(\(.*'\) *)/foo[\1]/c
```

The /c is for a prompt to confirm the replacement, and can be left off if desired.